# Cache stdout data and forward it stdout

Tags: linux, bash, pipe

I am running a command line tool in Linux that emits data every 10ms. I'll forward this to another application to visualize the data. I would like to cache for example 10 incoming messages from stdin and then release them to the visualization application as one stdout flush. For example:

```
10msApp | cache --size 10 | visualizer
```

Is there any application who caches stdin from a pipe?

Comment: Many applications will cache automatically when reading/writing through a pipe, and the challenge is to avoid the caching.

Comment: In this case the visualizer has a hard time to keep up with the repainting every 10ms so a repaint every 100ms would be much better. I think in this case caching makes absoluty sense. Don't you agree?

Comment: @Stefan That sounds like a job for input buffering on `visualizer`, it's that application's choice to repaint on every input line after all :-)

Answer (score 0):

Many applications, standard libraries, and frameworks already buffer to some extent when reading or writing to a pipe, so if you just want generic caching, it should likely already be there for you.

However, if that doesn't suit, `stdbuf` is provided by GNU coreutils (so more or less every Linux machine should have it), and can do this. However, it does it by data size rather than lines. For example:

```
stdbuf -o 1K 10msApp | visualizer
```

If `visualizer` also buffers its input, you may also need to run it with `stdbuf -i`.

`stdbuf` does also have line buffering with `-o L`, but as far as I know you cannot adjust the number of lines in the buffer.